# Javascript oninput(setTimeout 2s) / onchange - fire that comes as first

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, onchange

Hi I have a function Save that's triggered onchange event or oninput after 2s timeout.
Problem is that function Save is triggered twice in this scenario:

1. type something
2. wait 2s
3. oninput fires save event
4. click out of input
5. onchange fires save event

I need save only once depending on what happens first. If user types something and immediately leaves input, then save via onchange and oninput timeout should be cancelled. But if types something and waits 2s then save via oninput and onchange shouldn't be triggered.

I need some simple and clean solution. Does it exist? Thanks :)

edit: 
here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/TQ9KR/

```
jQuery('#text').on('change', function() {
        save();
});

jQuery('#text').on('input', function(){
    clearTimeout(this.delayer);

    var context = this;
    this.delayer = setTimeout(function () {
        jQuery(context).trigger('change');
    }, 2000);
});


function save(){
    jQuery('#a').text('saved on ' + new Date().getTime());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a flag to indicate whether save is needed:

```
jQuery('#text').on('change', function() {
    save();
});

jQuery('#text').on('input', function(){
    jQuery(this).data('unsaved', true);
    clearTimeout(this.delayer);

    var context = this;
    this.delayer = setTimeout(function () {
        jQuery(context).trigger('change');
    }, 2000);
});

function save(){
    if (jQuery('#text').data('unsaved')) {
        jQuery('#a').text('saved on ' + new Date().getTime());
        jQuery('#text').data('unsaved', false);
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TQ9KR/1/

**Update:** for your requirement of dealing also with changes to the field value from other JavaScript functions you could do the following instead (keeping your original `'change'` and `'input'` handlers:

```
function save(){
    var $text = jQuery('#text');
    if ($text.data('prevVal') != $text.val()) {
        jQuery('#a').text('saved on ' + new Date().getTime());
        $text.data('prevVal', $text.val());
    }
}
```

That is, only save if the current value of the field is different to whatever was saved last time (where the first time around it will automatically be different since there will be no previously saved value).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TQ9KR/2/

Comment: This could work. But I have another problem. If I change value of input via javascript and then I trigger onchange event it will not call save method because of flag.

Comment: OK, see my update, which is perhaps a better option either way since it only needs a change within the `save()` function, not within your original event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not add a data attribute, something like data-hasChanged and check that?

Answer (score 0):

well honestly only cleen solution that i can think of is to initialize global boolean variable that indicates has save hapen

```
var hasSaveHapen = false;
```

and now when any of those functions try to save use this:

```
if(!hasSaveHapen){
   do your save action
   hasSaveHapen = false;
}
```